# How to add custom AlertDialog entries to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

There's a RecyclerView in my activity and I want to add EditText entries (from Custom AlertDialog) to it. The Custom AlertDialog has an EditText and a Button to save the name.

What's the best way to do this? Should i make an Adapter Class for the AlertDialog or it's ok to set it up in the MainActivity class?

Here are the codes :

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

        Button addNewContactButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_newContact);
    }
```

**Contact:**

```
public class Contact {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**ContactAdapter:**

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public ContactAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contact,parent,false);
        return new ContactViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindContact(contacts.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact){
        this.contacts.add(contact);
        notifyItemInserted(this.contacts.size()-1);
    }

    public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameTextView;

        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_itemContact);
        }

        public void bindContact(Contact contact){
            nameTextView.setText(contact.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make a listener for the adapter and then implement the listener interface method in your MainActivity. And there you can show your custom alert. Hope, this helps!

Comment: Yes, add a listener, but not to the adapter. Add the listener to the custom dialog and handle the callback in the adapter

Comment: @Barns So you're saying I should make an Adapter class for my custom dialog?

Comment: No, Create a `DialogFragment` for your custom alert. Add a listener to the `DialogFragment`. From your `RecyclerView` use the `onClick` method on whichever object you want to trigger the onclick event.  In the `onclick` method you will open the `DialogFragment` to enter the data. When finished editing the data in the `DialogFragment` the listener will trigger the callback sending the data back to the `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Barns Thanks for helping. but i think I didn't explain what i'm trying to do correctly.  I don't want to click on RecyclerView's Items. There's a button in the Activity which opens a Dialog. what we enter in that dialog will be added to the RecyclerView.